# I am getting error while Regex replace javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var newInput = '{"id":"1","value":"Admin","prefix":"@"} asdas {"id":"24","value":"Ibiere Banigo","prefix":"@"}';

var gettingJson = newInput.match(/\{\"(.*?)\"\}/g);
var finalString = '';
$.each(gettingJson, function (index, value) {
   var data = JSON.parse(value);
   finalString = newInput.replace(/\{\"(.*?)\"\}/g, '@[' + data.id + ']');
});
console.log(finalString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code I am trying to replace this the parenthesis with @[id] it is replacing it but for all like I want my output to be

```
@[1] someone new @[2]
```

but instead I am getting

```
@[2] someone new @[2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem with your approach is the `replace` method replaces all matching occurrences.

**Solution**

Use `replace` method [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```
replace(regexp, replacerFunction)
```

```js
var newInput = '{"id":"1","value":"Admin","prefix":"@"} asdas {"id":"24","value":"Ibiere Banigo","prefix":"@"}';

var finalString = newInput.replace(/\{\"(.*?)\"\}/g, match => {
  var data = JSON.parse(match);
  return '@[' + data.id + ']'
})

console.log(finalString);
```